# Macro errors out because autofilter doesn't have a value

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have written a macro to call some records from a worksheet based on manually entered user settings.  The code I'm using is shown below:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Serial Number Data")

Sheets("Serial Number Data").Select

sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 7, Range("project").Value
sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 8, Range("platform").Value
sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, Range("equipment").Value
```

The problem is there are combinations of these filters that don't exist.  When the user enters values for a combination that doesn't exist, the macro errors out.  Is there a way to set a flag and send an error message in the macro if a value isn't valid.  I have looked at making dependent filters for the inputs to eliminate the error on the front end but there are probably 100 combinations that would have to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Application.CountIfs` to determine if the combination of those values exists or not:

```
With sh.UsedRange
    If Application.CountIfs(.Columns(7), sh.Range("project").Value, _
                            .Columns(8), sh.Range("platform").Value, _
                            .Columns(9), sh.Range("equipment").Value) = 0 Then
         ' Combination not found
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to solve the issue.  The next operation of the macro was to cut and paste to a different worksheet.  I found out that it got this far without the error occurring.  Of course there was not data, so I used If Worksheets("myrange").Range ("b13").Value = "" Then set an error flag and end the macro.